# Creating and querying tables with JPA - How to return multiple rows?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I would like to create such tables in MySQL with Hibernate/JPA.

```
SENSOR: PK_SENSOR_ID, SENSOR_NAME, SENSOR_URL

SENSOR_DATA: FK_SENSOR_ID, DATE, TIME, VALUE
```

SENSOR_DATA will contain readings from multiple sensors. Then I would like to have a method which use this query:

```
"SELECT AVG(VALUE), DATE, SENSOR_NAME, FROM SENSOR, SENSOR_DATA WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-02' AND SENSOR_ID = FK_SENSOR_ID GROUP BY DATE"
```

It would return an array of an average values of 'value' per each day (with date and sensor_name).

At this moment I know that I have to create a model for SENSOR with @Entity but what about SENSOR_DATA?

So far, I tried to create a simple model, repository and service with date, time and value and then query it but the problem was that I was able to only get single row for a single day. In this way I would have to create lots of objects for each day separately which doesn't make sense. I assume that it was because of that I used `@Entity` and added id, but I couldn't figure out a different solution. What I want is to create a single `Sensor` object and then query through `SENSOR_DATA` table.

Stack: Spring Boot, Spring Boot Data JPA Starter, Hibernate, MySQL, Lombok,

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think the sql you have will work because of the group by. Correct me if I am wrong.

If you using Hibernate and Spring data jpa. You can do new Object in hql.

Say if the entity that mapped to SENSOR_DATA is sensorDate.

And your sensor object has constructor (double ave, Date date, String sensorName)

Example:

```
@Query("select new path/to/Sensor(avg, date, sensorName) 
       from sensorDate sd 
       where sd.date <:fromDate and sd.date > :toDate and sd=:fksd)")
public list<Sensor> findSensor(@Param("fromDate")Date fromDate, @Param("toDate")Date toDate,  @Param("fksd")SensorDate fksd);
```

Let me explain:

when new keyword, hibernate will convert the output of the sql and mapped to sensor object and into list. Also since you are using hibernate, it is better to use ORM, when compare id, you can just compare the object, internally hibernate will convert hql to sql and compare their pk.

I am making a lot of assumption, but you get the idea. As long as you can get the value you want, you can do a new and pass them into the pojos you have.

Comment: I am sure that this sql query worked as I tried it on mock db.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't figure out how to do it with JPA, I just used Spring JDBC and it works great. I based on a example implementation from this link:
[Link](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jdbc-example)